# Can granite countertops rest on plastic corner braces?

Tags: cabinets, kitchen-counters

Some plastic corner braces included with Ready To Assemble cabinets have lips that sit on top of the plywood cabinet sides.  Do these lips need removed in order to keep the granite from sitting on these smaller points of contact, to distribute its weight more evenly?

[image]

Comment: Every stone countertop I have ever put in had a plywood "sub-top" installed on the cabinets under the granite. Check with your installer about what they require.

Comment: @Kyle, our soapstone countertop is installed over the cabinets with no plywood sheet on top. The stone is supported only on the edges. Was installed ca 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going over the tops of all the base cabinets with grinder of sander to remove any high spots.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not going to matter.  Installers will typically be using a silicon to secure the counter top to the cabinet tops and the thickness of the silicon is likely to be taller than that lip.  Also unless your cabinets are dead level the counter top people will be using shims in various places.

If it does matter your counter top installer should be competent enough to handle that detail.